# Wpf animation OnCloseing cause fire Close event two time

Tags: c#, wpf, events, animation

I use a base window class for my application windows.

- `BaseWindow`
- `MainWindow`

Now, i wrote an animation inside `OnClosing` in `BaseWindow` class like this:

```
void AnimationWindowBase_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!CloseAnimationIsDone)
    {
        ((CancelEventArgs) e).Cancel = true;
        var closeAnimation1 = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            From = RestoreBounds.Top,
            To = RestoreBounds.Top + 10,
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
        };
        closeAnimation1.Completed += (s, eArgs) =>
        {
            CloseAnimationIsDone = true;

            // This line cause fire close again in MainWindow class
            Close();
        };
        BeginAnimation(TopProperty, closeAnimation1);

        BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, new DoubleAnimation
        {
            From = 1,
            To = 0,
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
        });
    }
}
```

But if i have a `OnClosing` method inside `MainWindow` like this:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    AppConfigs.SaveAll();
}
```

Then settings will be saved **2** Time!

How can i resolve it with a good way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of subscribing to the `Closing` event, try overriding the `OnClosing` method. The `OnClosing` of the base window can have the same code as your `AnimationWindowBase_Closing` method. But in the main window you can do it like this:

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosing(e);

    if (!e.Cancel)
        AppConfigs.SaveAll();
}
```